# Hide index.php from url using htaccess not work as expected

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using this [filemanager library](https://github.com/prasathmani/tinyfilemanager) in a folder of my local apache server. I've done a bit of configuration and renamed the php file to index.php. I want hide from the url the `index.php?p=`

I've added this code to an htaccess file but it's the same used by wordpress and seems not working as expected

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /ext/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ext/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options All -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You write: "seems not working as expected". So what _did_ you expect exactly? And how _does_ it work, _exactly_ ? Be precise! What _exactly_ happens if you make test requests? What does the browser show, what happens?

Comment: When I insert the url in browser in this case `localhost/ext/` at the moment it will appear `index.php?p=` into the url and this isn't what I want. I want to be able to automatically rewrite all the params to index so I can have a clean url

Comment: The script uses `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to assemble the value of the `FM_SELF_URL` constant (https://github.com/prasathmani/tinyfilemanager/blob/master/tinyfilemanager.php#L272C103-L272C123) - and that value is always the name of the executed PHP script, even if it was invoked by requesting just the directory. Since you already made manipulations (renaming the script), and therefor updatability doesn't appear to be your highest priority, your best bet is probably to change it in this place directly.

Comment: Because the script already explicitly redirects to you to `foldername/index.php?p=` first - so you would have to "counter" that with an external redirect from `foldername/index.php?p=` to `foldername/?p=` first of all, if you wanted to leave the script as-is.

Comment: Can you show an example of fixing my issue?